# Embedding Python Code in a Word Document?

Tags: python, ms-word, libreoffice

I am writing a manual using `Word` / `LibreOffice's Writer`.

As part of the manual, I'd like to include `python` code snippets. 
Naturally, I want these to be included in a `nice` way.

How can I paste `python` code into `Word` / `LibreOffice's Writer` while keeping its nice format?

Comment: You'd be better off use a a plain text markup format, like Docbook, AsciiDoc and reStructuredText. They work perfectly for technical documentation, can be handled by source control, and usually have some way to mark source code (and usually can be taught to run them through a source highlighter).

Comment: @delnan: thank you. Do these work under `Ubuntu`?

Comment: [Docbook](http://docbook.org/) may be installed by default, [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) is available as package. As for reStructuredText, I haven't heard of many people using the bare-bones reference implementation in Python's `docutils`, it seems be used mostly via [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org).

Comment: Why not just use (La)tex with the listings package? That already supports python and has many useful advanced uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libre Office should be able to import HTML code. You can use any Highlighter that can output HTML highlighted code. You may try an online highlighter like http://www.tohtml.com/python/ for example.

Edit:
Somehow Libre Office is missing HTML code in the Paste Special menu, but here is some trick to get html into the document:

1. save your html code to a html file
2. open the html file with libre office (select web page as format)
3. select everything and hit copy
4. paste into the document you want it to be in

This is cumbersome, but I didn't find another way, though I can remember, that there was a HTML option in the Paste Special menu in Open Office. May be there is some plugin or similar stuff to do it easier.

Comment: Thank you. The question is then, how do I import the HTML code into `Libre Office`? when I paste it -- it just appears as regular text.

Comment: sorry, was thinking about open office instead of libre I think... added some workaround, but this way is just cumbersome =(